# Create new delimiters

Tags: delimiters

I would like to define new sets of delimiters for my document, but I cannot use packages like `fdsymbol` or `MnSymbol` because conflicts arise (I'm already using too many fonts). Specifically, I'm interested in defining *double* and *triple* parentheses / brackets / braces / angled brackets, and single angled brackets with a dot inside (similar to what `\lBrack`, `\lAngle` and `\langledot` do in `fdsymbol`), and the delimiters should be extensible by using modifiers such as `\big` and `\left`/`\right`. The ultimate objective is to use these delimiters to create shortcuts like those defined in the `physics` package, where e.g. `\braket{a}{b}` prints out something like <a|b>.

The code is probably similar to what @egreg does in [this answer][1], but he defines custom math relations instead of delimiters, and I'm afraid I don't have the necessary know-how to translate this into the code I need.

Comment: No extensible delimiters without defining a math symbol font, sorry.

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to import just those selected few from the fonts used in those packages, without calling them?

Comment: @giobrach You can avoid loading the packages, but you will still have to load a math symbol font. So if you already use too many, it will not help you.

Comment: are you sure you really need 16 math families in your math setup, why are you using so many? or you could switch to luatex which allows 256 families.